# virtuemart3 shows 2 images with mouse hover

Tags: joomla3.0, virtuemart

I need to show 2 images per products in categories menu. Please refer
 [this](http://velikorodnov.com/virtuemart/reviver/index.php/men) link for more clarification.
To do this ,I have used below code in sublayouts folder and products.php files:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
                               <?php
                                        $image = $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageFirst" id="Img_to_Js_'.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'" border="0"',false) ;
                                        if(!empty($product->images[1])){
                                         $image2 = $product->images[1]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageSecond"  border="0"',false) ;
                                        } else {$image2= $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageSecond"  border="0"',false) ;}
                                        echo JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),'<div class="front">'.$image.'</div><div class="back">'.$image2.'</div>');
                                ?>
                                </div>
```

but didn't work out.It shows only one image
live demo: http://new.decoricor.com/decoricor-jewelery/hair-style

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden configuration to show more than one picture in the category view.
You can set values here: 
/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/virtuemart.cfg

prodimg_browse needs to be set to 2. prodimg_browse=2

This is called in the view.html.php of the category view.

After that, two pictures will be in your array.

Documentation for the hidden configuration:
http://docs.virtuemart.net/manual/general-concepts/206-hidden-configurations.html